# Validation in a modal form

Tags: css, html, asp-classic

I am updating our site that is used for our people to enter in orders.  The first page gathers the customer information.  The user currently clicks on a button that brings them to a secondary page where they can enter part of the customers name and it will return the correct customer code.  The site is written in asp using sql.

I am trying, with html5, css and asp, to redesign the form so when the user clicks on the button, they will get a modal form where they can enter in part of the customers name.  It would then return the id number and put it on the main page and close the modal form or it would return a not found error.

I have the asp code but where I am having an issue is how to load up the modal form.  I can show a modal form from a page - but how should I handle the validation?  The form itself is basically written in the html 5 page.

Thank you for your input.

George

Comment: Are you validating server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then this is already supported. Each form element can have `required` to validate against empty input fields.

You can go further with changing the `type` attribute. For example this one requires email addresses:

```
<input type="email" required placeholder="Enter your email address" value="" />
```